# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method, Method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, linq

I got this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not
>   recognize the method 'Boolean isValid(System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal
>   ])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

This is my code:

```
private void ReadAll(Entities context)
{
  var allPromotions = 
  (from pro in context.PROMOS.AsNoTracking()
  join krig in context.KRIGS.AsNoTracking() on pro.PROM_ID equals 
  krig.PROM_ID
  where isValid(pro.PROM_ID, pro.VALUE)
  group new ItemList
  {
   Id = krig.KRIG_ID,
   Quantity = krig.KRIG_VALUE.HasValue ? krig.KRIG_VALUE.ToString() : "1",
  } 
  by pro into proGrpup
  select new Promotion
  {
   Id = proGrpup.Key.PROM_ID,
   Description = proGrpup.Key.DESCRIPT,
  }
  ).ToList();
}

**//Done for logging purposes**
 private bool isValid(string promId, decimal? value)
{
  if (value < 0)
  {
   //write log
   return false;
  }
  else
   return true;
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: AFAIC it is not possible to use pure CLR methods like that, you might need to change that to `Expression<Func<PROMO, bool>>`

Comment: MethodCallExpression is required in this case, but that too will only work with in same memory context not remote processing

Comment: Can you give me an example how to use the Expression<Func<PROMO, bool>>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void ReadAll(Entities context)

    {

        var allPromotions =

        (from pro in context.PROMOS.AsNoTracking()

            join krig in context.KRIGS.AsNoTracking() on pro.PROM_ID equals

            krig.PROM_ID

            where pro.VALUE >= 0

            group new ItemList

            {

                Id = krig.KRIG_ID,

                Quantity = krig.KRIG_VALUE.HasValue ? krig.KRIG_VALUE.ToString() : "1",

            }

            by pro into proGrpup

            select new Promotion

            {

                Id = proGrpup.Key.PROM_ID,

                Description = proGrpup.Key.DESCRIPT,

            }

        ).ToList();

    }
```

You are trying to put your own business (log) into a linq-to-entity query. It's simply that it is impossible. Your business may be simple or complex. Entity framework can't handle this situation. WHERE clause was born to help to filter data and that's it. If you want to log somewhere, it is better to separate it from entity framework query

Comment: that's the reason that i created this function

Comment: You are trying to put your own business (log) into a linq-to-entity query. It's simply that it is impossible. Your business may be simple or complex. Entity framework can't handle this situation. WHERE clause was born to help to filter data and that's it. If you want to log somewhere, it is better to separate it from entity framework query